# sympy lambdify with numexpr and sqrt

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numexpr

I'm trying to speed up some numeric code generated by `lambdify` using `numexpr`. Unfortunately, the `numexpr`-based function breaks when using the `sqrt` function, even though it's one of the [supported functions](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr#supported-functions).

This reproduces the issue for me:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
import numexpr

from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

expr = sympy.S('b*sqrt(a) - a**2')
a, b = sorted(expr.free_symbols, key=lambda s: s.name)

func_numpy = lambdify((a,b), expr, modules=[np], dummify=False)
func_numexpr = lambdify((a,b), expr, modules=[numexpr], dummify=False)

foo, bar = np.random.random((2, 4))

print sympy.__version__
print func_numpy(foo, bar)
print func_numexpr(foo, bar)
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
0.7.6
[-0.02062061  0.08648306 -0.57868128  0.27598245]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sympy_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print func_numexpr(foo, bar)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

As a sanity check, I also tried calling `numexpr` directly:

```
numexpr.evaluate('b*sqrt(a) - a**2', local_dict=dict(a=foo, b=bar))
```

which works as expected, producing the same result as `func_numpy`.

---

**EDIT**: It works when I use the line:

```
func_numexpr = lambdify((a,b), expr, modules=['numexpr'], dummify=False)
```

Is this a sympy bug?

Comment: I'm not sure if ``lambdify()`` works with `numexpr`. E.g, ``numexpr.sqrt()`` does not exist.

Comment: See my edit. It works with the string 'numexpr', but not the module object itself.

Comment: filed an issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9334

Comment: And the fix: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/9335

Answer (score -1):

you can change `np.sqrt(9)` to `numexpr.evaluate('9**0.5')`

Comment: That would completely ruin the point of using sympy, wouldn't it?